# Show factorization $ x^{2n}-1=(x^2-1) \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x^2-2x \cos \frac{\pi k}{n} + 1) $

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, prime-factorization

I'm interested in how to show that
$$
x^{2n}-1=(x^2-1) \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x^2-2x \cos \frac{\pi k}{n} + 1)
$$
I've seen this equality too often, but have no idea how to derive it. I've tried the following:

$$
x^{2n}-1=(x^n-1)(x^n+1)
$$

We all know that $x^n-1=(x-\xi^0)(x-\xi^1) \dots (x-\xi^{n-1})$,  where $\xi=\exp(i \cdot \frac{2 \pi}{n})$.

Here $x-\xi^0$ gives us the desired $x-1$(for $x^2-1$ in RHS).

But the problem is, we can not do the same with $x^n+1$, because as I understand, there is no such general factorization of $x^n+1$. Firstly, it depends whether $n$ is even or not. Secondly, if for the sake for simplicity $n$ is odd, then we can decompose the polynomial such a way:
$$x^n+1=(x+1)(1-x+x^2-x^3 \dots -x^{n-2}+x^{n-1})$$

I don't see here anything to continue with. Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider directly $ x^{2n } - 1 = \prod ( x - \zeta_{2n} ^ k)$. Figure out what $ ( x - \zeta_{2n} ) ( x - \zeta_{2n} ^ { 2n -k } ) $ is equal to . The leftover terms correspond to $ k = 0, n$, which give us $ (x-1)(x+1) = (x^2 - 1)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin:  Did you mean $(x-\zeta_{2n}^\color{red}k)(x-\zeta_{2n}^{2n-k})$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Yes indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @CalvinLin for this post. The idea was *to apply direct* substitution
$$
x^{2n}-1=\prod_{k=0}^{2n-1} (x-\xi^k)
$$
where $\xi$ is a base root of the equation $x^{2n}-1=0$, e.g. $\xi=\exp({i \cdot \frac{\pi}{n}})$.

It gives us the following:
$$
\prod_{k=0}^{2n-1} (x-\xi^k)=(x-\xi^0)(x-\xi^n) \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (x-\xi^k)(x-\xi^{2n-k})
$$

$(x-\xi^0)(x-\xi^n)=(x-1)(x+1)=(x^2-1)$ since $\xi^n=\exp(i \cdot \pi)=-1$

Now let's take a deeper look at multiplier inside the product notation.
$$
(x-\xi^k)(x-\xi^{2n-k})=x^2-(\xi^k+\xi^{2n-k})x+\xi^k \cdot \xi^{2n-k}
$$

Obviously, $\xi^k \cdot \xi^{2n-k}=\xi^{2n}=1$. Consider the coefficient at $x$:
$$
\xi^k+\xi^{2n-k} \\
=\cos(k\cdot \frac{\pi}{n})+i\sin(k\cdot\frac{\pi}{n})+\cos((2n-k)\cdot \frac{\pi}{n})+i\sin((2n-k)\cdot \frac{\pi}{n})\\
=\cos(k\cdot \frac{\pi}{n})+i\sin(k\cdot\frac{\pi}{n})+\cos(2\pi - k\cdot \frac{\pi}{n})+i\sin(2\pi - k\cdot \frac{\pi}{n}) \\
=2\cos(k\cdot \frac{\pi}{n})
$$

The last equality comes from the periodicity and evenness/oddness of $\cos$/$\sin$.

So, for now we have:
$$
=(x^2-1)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}(x^2-2x\cos(k \cdot \frac{\pi}{n})+1)
$$

And we are done!

Comment: Note that the "it gives us the following" is not correct. You currently do not have $ ( x - \zeta^n)$, and have $ ( x - \zeta^0) = (x - \zeta^{2n}$ repeated. That is why I referred to these terms as "leftover". Apart from that, this looks good.

Comment: @CalvinLin corrected, thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Note

\begin{align}
x^{2n}-1
&=\prod_{k=0}^{2n-1} (x-e^{i\frac{\pi k}n})
=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (x-e^{i\frac{\pi k}n})\cdot 
\underset{k=2n-j}{ \prod_{k=n}^{2n-1} (x-e^{i\frac{\pi k}n})}\\
&=(x-1)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (x-e^{i\frac{\pi k}n})
\cdot \prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (x-e^{-i\frac{\pi j}n}) (x-e^{-i \pi})\\
 &=(x-1)(x+1)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (x-e^{i\frac{\pi k}n})
(x-e^{-i\frac{\pi k}n})\\
 &=(x^2-1)\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} (x^2 - 2x\cos\frac{\pi k}n+1)
\\
\end{align}

Comment: High @Quanto. That's a good one.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You can use the same idea in the factorization of $x^n-1$.

Think of
$$x^n=-1=e^{i(2k+1)\pi}$$